# Hiding the folder structure from users in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

How do I hide my source folders from users that belong to a particular group? I tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh561425(v=vs.110).aspx#RestrictAccess), but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In source control explorer, right click on the folder you want to hide and select Security (under Advanced). There you should be able to set a **deny** permission for **read** for the team/group that you want.