# Visual Studio Online - Possible to prevent solution downloading?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a "Read-only" user account within Visual Studio Online. I've created the user and set all permissions to "Deny" except for "View project-level information", which is set at "Allow".

I've noticed that the user still has the ability to download the solution in its entirety and/or by directory. Is it possible to disable/prevent downloading functionality?

Ideally, I'd like only for this user to browse the solution's directory-tree and corresponding file contents.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've been exploring the Azure Active Directory integration to see if such permissions could be set there -- has proven to still be inconclusive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding the folder structure from users in TFS 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573981/hiding-the-folder-structure-from-users-in-tfs-2013)

Answer (score 0):

There is a default `Readers` group (see `https://`*your_account*`.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/`*your_project*`/_admin/_security`).

Add the user to this group, and do not forget to restore the defaults permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If people can read the files, then you can't prevent them downloading those files. In any case, even if you could, once the source is on screen people can always copy and paste the contents.

The 'Read' permission will only stop them from uploading any changes.